# Maximum likelihood estimation of GARCH modelling in R

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, garch

I want to estimate parameters of different versions of GARCH models with different distributional assumptions using maximum likelihood estimation (MLE).

Therefore I want to construct my own functions.

For example

- I will first specify the GARCH model version
- Then, I will specify the distribution of the error term
- Finally, I will estimate the specified model.

However, I need to be guided. I am familiar with GARCH models and also with MLE. But I have some confusion applying in R. I will be very glad for any advice about sources, articles. I made a search on google. However, I was confused again. I need direct targets to understand better.

Comment: Are you able to implement a GARCH(1,1) in R? If not, what is the problem? Also, it seems your question might be off topic because as currently formulated it does not address any statistical aspect of GARCH modelling.

Comment: I am able to. However, I want to implement GARCH process with exogenous variables with different distributional assumtions other than normal distirbution.

Comment: You have not said that in your post. Please edit it to narrow it down to a concrete problem you are facing. Show us how far you got and where you got stuck.